# How to pass an email to Shopify checkout

Tags: shopify

I'm working with an external analytics app that requires us to collect email on the /cart page. To save the customer from having to enter their email address again, I'm wondering if there's a way to send that email to the payment form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ryan! One of the hallmarks of a good question is displaying prior effort. Have you made any attempts thus far to do this?

Comment: Hi @corsiKa, I'm uncertain how prior effort applies to my question. Shopify uses the shopify tag here as their official support channel ([source](http://www.shopify.com/technology/6168080-using-stack-overflow-as-your-official-support-platform)). This question is directed at the Shopify support team.

Comment: Enter their email where? Why not just tie into the orders/create webhook and do whatever fancy analytics magic you need to do there?

Comment: I'm totally new to shopify, could you tell me more about the orders/create webhook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shopify API to interact with orders, specifically looking at the [API documentation](http://api.shopify.com) you should be able to achieve what you want.

1. Which language do you code in?/Can you code in?/Would you like to achieve this in? (For example, Ruby, PHP, ASP..)
2. You can access a users email address from the Order if you know the Order ID.. 
   The Order ID can be found by querying the Shopify orders API based on whatever your criteria are.
3. Alternatively as per Csaunders answer you can use a [Shopify Web-hook](http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHook) which will notify your server when a specific event happens - think of it as an event trigger.. For example:

> 1. Customer raises an order
> 2. Shopify notices your shop has a web-hook active and so uses it
> 3. Your web-system receives all of the order info over a POST request in XML format
> 4. You extract the Email address (for example $email = trim($xml->email); )
> 5. Push the $email you extracted to whatever your analytics system is

Without further info about your case and setup and what knowledge you have I will struggle to improve this answer - if however you come back and add some more detail or comment on this post I will try to help as best I can.

Thanks